# Codeigniter calling controller function keep redirect to index.php

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter

I am using CodeIgniter 3 on Centos 7 with Nginx and php-fpm.
Locally my project works well, but when I try to transfer it to my web host it does not.

I simply create some User.php controller:

```
public function test(){
  echo 'Hello World';
}
```

Also, I use this .htaccess:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php)
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

I can call the controller but the function does not work, it will just redirect to index.php and the `echo` does not work.

How would I solve this issue?

Comment: Do you get any errors in the logs or something similar?

Comment: no error in log file.

Comment: check the controller constructor my it check for login session, also Make sure your controller name start with capital letter and the file name start with capital letter

Comment: @AbanoubMakram everything is correct as this is working on localhost now I wanted to transfer it to my webhost.

Comment: try this `<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
</IfModule>
and make this alternation to your application/config/config.php file:

$config['index_page'] = '';`

Comment: @AbanoubMakram ok ill try

Comment: @AbanoubMakram doesnt work :(

Comment: ok, when you type www.yourdmoain.com/User/test/  you said it redirect to index.php please can you give me the url after redirect ?

Comment: what about your base_url in you config.php ?

Comment: read this https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/recipes/codeigniter/

Comment: @AbanoubMakram base_url = 'http://example.com'; --> mydomain

Comment: @AbanoubMakram when i try to follow it and replace my recipe i end up 502 log error in nginx: connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream

Comment: @AbanoubMakram I used this ----> location ~ \.php($|/) {
        fastcgi_pass  unix:/var/run/php-fpm/php-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index  index.php;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(.*)$;
        fastcgi_param   PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include        fastcgi_params;
    }

Comment: i'm not experience in nginx i tried to help you by few search

Comment: "base_url = 'example.com';" It should be `'http://example.com'`.

Comment: https://github.com/wolfgang1983/htaccess_for_codeigniter

Comment: Thanks a lot but the problem seems to be php-fpm in php70w its working now that i downgrade it to php5.4